# How do you write a mysql query that returns the latest respective records?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Using the table (Messages) data structure:

```
+------+--------+--------+----------+------+--------+
|  id  | FromId |  ToId  | sentdate | text |  index |
+------+--------+--------+----------+------+--------+
| guid |    200 |    100 |  3/9/20  |  2c  |    6   |
| guid |    400 |    100 |  3/8/20  |  4a  |    5   |
| guid |    100 |    200 |  3/8/20  |  2b  |    4   |
| guid |    300 |    100 |  3/7/20  |  3a  |    3   |
| guid |    200 |    100 |  3/6/20  |  2a  |    2   |
| guid |    300 |    200 |  3/5/20  |  1a  |    1   |
+------+--------+--------+----------+------+--------+

SELECT * 
FROM `Messages` 
WHERE FromId IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT FromId 
    FROM `Messages` 
    WHERE ToId = '100')
GROUP BY FromId ORDER BY index DESC
```

The expected results should be (newest record from each sender):

```
+------+--------+--------+----------+------+--------+
|  id  | fromid |  toid  | sentdate | text |  index |
+------+--------+--------+----------+------+--------+
| guid |    200 |    100 |  3/9/20  |  2c  |    6   |
| guid |    400 |    100 |  3/8/20  |  4a  |    5   |
| guid |    300 |    100 |  3/7/20  |  3a  |    3   |
+------+--------+--------+----------+------+--------+
```

However, after doing GROUP BY, the following results occur (incorrect sorting):

```
+------+--------+--------+----------+------+--------+
|  id  | fromid |  toid  | sentdate | text |  index |
+------+--------+--------+----------+------+--------+
| guid |    400 |    100 |  3/8/20  |  4a  |    5   |
| guid |    300 |    100 |  3/7/20  |  3a  |    3   |
| guid |    200 |    100 |  3/6/20  |  2a  |    2   |
+------+--------+--------+----------+------+--------+
```

How do you get the latest records distinctively from each sender optimized without returning all records?  I've tried JOINs and ORDER BY in the subquery, with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want entire records, you need *filtering*, not *aggregation*.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select m.*, row_number() over(partition by fromid order by sentdate desc) rn
    from messages m
) t
where rn = 1
```

You can also filter with a correlated subquery (this will work on older versions of MySQL):

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.sentdate = (
    select max(m1.sentdate) from messages m1 where m1.fromid = m.fromid
)
```

With an index on `(fromid, sentdate)`, the correlated subquery might be an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to think it the other way around: you need the records with the highest index for each FromId

```
SELECT * FROM 'Messages' WHERE id IN (
   SELECT MAX(index) 
   FROM 'Messages' 
   WHERE ToId = 100 
   GROUP BY FromId
)
```

and then you can sort it anyway you want

Comment: The id column is a GUID format (9d245322-809c-463d-8803-559fb39483d8).